# Calculate average scores from 6 possible columns with Null and Not Null values

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table and want to get the average score for each student。

[image]

To be more specific, scoremonth1 has more weight to be calculated than 2,3,4,5 and 6 (1>2>3>4>5>6). And we should add no more than 3 monthly scores from the table.

For instance, the average score for Tom should be (80+90)/2 since there are only 2 scores available. As for Marry, the average score should be (90+70+80)/3 since those are the three monthly scores with more weight. And again, for Anna, the average score should be (90+100+70)/3

In my case, there would be over 100 students. Except listing all the possible cases like CASE WHEN scoremonth1 is not null, scoremonth2 is NULL. etc to calculate the average, what else method could do the calculation dynamically?

I know there is a SQL function coalesce to return the first not null value, but how could I get the second and third not null values? And is there a way to track which monthlyscores are added up?  I really appreciate your help!

Comment: Your biggest issue is your table is not normalised - would you have 100 columns if there happened to be 100 months in a year? A table with `StudentId` and `Date` would require a simple `sum()` and your query is easy.

Answer (score 2):

Stu mentioned your underlying issue. To normalize your data without changing table design you can use cross apply...

```
select student, sum(score)
from table
cross apply (
   values(1,scoremonth1),(2,scoremonth2),(3,scoremonth3)) as scores(month,score)
group by student
```

I strongly suggest you redesign so you don't have to manage this query when adding months by creating a new table called studentScores.

```
create table studentscores
(
    student varchar(200)
    ,scoremonth int
    ,score decimal(5,2)
)
```

And then populate it like this...

```
insert into studentScores(student,scoremonth,score)
select ca.*
from table
cross apply
   (values 
   (student,1,scoremonth1)
   ,(student,2,scoremonth2)
   ,(student,3,scoremonth3)
   ,(student,4,scoremonth4)
   ,(student,5,scoremonth5)
   ) ca(ca1,ca2,ca3)
where ca3 is not null
```

And finally, usse it like this...

```
select ss.student, sum(score), count(*) NumOfScores, sum(score)/Count(*) avg
from table
  join studentscores ss on ss.student=table.student
where ss.scoremonth between 1 and 3
group by ss.student
```

Comment: I was literally about to post almost exactly the same, so +1

Comment: Hi KeithL and Stu, thanks for helping out.  For insert statement, there are student, month1,month2, month3 , month4 and month5 columns after cross apply. How could it be inserted into the table with the three columns you created named studentScores? I have tried it in SQL server, but it failed. Could you check what is going on? Thank you!!

Comment: the cross apply in the insert is converting 5 columns into 3 columns on up to 5 rows per record (student).

Comment: Normally you would be storing an ID and not the student name, but that was not available.

Comment: @Stu, I really prefer this method vs unpivot as I feel it is easier to explain to someone.

Comment: @Savannah if this answered your question please consider "accepting" it.

Comment: I got a notification on this but it looks like the fix here is ca.* to fill table